# How, if, does the inside air of a football influence it's motion?

Tags: kinematics, acoustics, air

And before me lies a football. Say it's filled with pressurized air. If I kick it, how will the inside air be influenced? Will the kick induce soundwaves? Can the ball give a sound? Will it influence the trajectory?

Comment: The kick will excite sound waves (you can hear it), and strictly speaking those sound waves will affect the trajectory.  However, I would imagine that the influence would be negligible compared to the impact of the air flowing around the football.

Comment: @MichaelM Ah yes. Could we produce a sound resonance inside the ball?

Comment: Of course, as long as the football is not rigid or not infinitely dense a kick will excite resonances inside.  Those resonances will (slightly) deform the boundary of the football, which will in turn (slightly) affect the flow around the football and its trajectory.  But I do not feel comfortable estimating the magnitude of that affect.